# SwingX how to get child components of JXMonthView?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

Anyone had experience with using SwingX? 
I want to use JXMonthView and modify its components. I can use it without a sweat. 
But when I try to actually get my hands on the underlying child components I fail. 
I would like to change the font style and color used only by the component which displays the month. 
I am using SwingX 1.6.2.

Comment: @jzd @kleopatra +1 to you all for help with this one. I wonder why I didn't plus you before? Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, a JXMonthView *has no* components to modify (for the one exception, see below). Instead, it's painting is done by a rendering mechanism, similar to rendering of cells a table/tree/list. The SwingX'ish way to customize the visual properties of the rendering is to decorate the rendering component by a Highlighter.

Unfortunately, the evolution got stuck somewhere in the middle: there's no easy and no really public support to do so. The collaborators are in plaf.basic:

- CalendarRenderingHandler: the interface to implement
- BasicCalendarRenderingHandler: a package-private default implementation
- BasicMonthViewUI: has a factory method to create and return the handler to use

So customizing the visuals of a JXMonthView is quite a chore, involving a lot of subclassing. On the brighter side: swinglabs-demos has an example of how that can be done

[MonthViewExtDemo](http://java.net/projects/swinglabs-demos/sources/svn/show/trunk/SwingXSet6/swingxdemos/src/org/jdesktop/swingx/demos/monthviewext?rev=1280)

CU
Jeanette

PS: you might consider to post SwingX specific questions at the [SwingLabs Forum](http://www.java.net/forums/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs) - though it's not as active as it used to be, due to migration woes of java.net, sigh

Comment: Thanks. Both answers were very helpful and useful. I accepted this one only because using this example was easier for me to understand that I will ever have more control over a calendar widget if I build my own :) Seriously the JXMonthView is a nice piece of code, very easy to use, though no really meant for situations when you desire to modify it. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just get the MonthViewUI and make the changes you need.  Take a look at the [`JXMonthView` source](http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/content/trunk/swingx-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMonthView.java).

Comment: OK. I am looking into it at the moment, but can you think of a simple example that would help me get it faster how to do it?

Comment: @Boro, not sure.  Would have to see example code.  Sounds like that should be another question.

Comment: Honestly I read the doc, and I wrote my own UI. I installed it, I created header handler etc. No success. I always end up with the default look, why?! 
For example I would at least to be able to install the SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler, can you help me with this, please fa silly example would be a blast. I love the lib but I do not get why they do not expose child components so you can get them with getComponents(): http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx/1.6.1/swingx-1.6.1-sources.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/plaf/basic/SpinningCalendarHeaderHandler.java?format=ok

Comment: Can you, for example, show me how to change the header from basic to the spinner one, link in my previous comment? Thanks.